# Как запустить корутину в Unity по закрытию программы на c#?

Tags: c#, unity3d

пробовал сделать так, но ничего не вышло(

```
private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    StartCoroutine(Timer());
 }
```

Comment: Каким образом **закрытая** unity должна запускать и следить за корутиной?

Comment: ну просто те корутины, которые запускаются при старте отлично работают в фоновом режиме

Comment: Потому что их запуском занимается главный поток unity? Каким образом эти корутины должны работать после завершения этого  потока?

Comment: я понял, спасибо, что объяснили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак - это невозможно. [Запуском и управлением корутин занимается основной поток Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Корутины (как и все, что создано внутри Unity) заканчивает свою жизнедеятельность вместе с Unity.